# Not able to see Kubernetes UI Dashboard

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

I have set up a cluster where there are 2 nodes. One is Master and Other is a node, both on different Azure ubuntu VMs.  For networking, I used Canal tool. 

`$ kubectl get nodes
NAME             STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
ubuntu-aniket1   Ready     master    57m       v1.10.0
ubutu-aniket     Ready     <none>    56m       v1.10.0`

`$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                     READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   canal-jztfd                              3/3       Running   0          57m
kube-system   canal-mdbbp                              3/3       Running   0          57m
kube-system   etcd-ubuntu-aniket1                      1/1       Running   0          58m
kube-system   kube-apiserver-ubuntu-aniket1            1/1       Running   0          58m
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-ubuntu-aniket1   1/1       Running   0          58m
kube-system   kube-dns-86f4d74b45-8zqqr                3/3       Running   0          58m
kube-system   kube-proxy-k5ggz                         1/1       Running   0          58m
kube-system   kube-proxy-vx9sq                         1/1       Running   0          57m
kube-system   kube-scheduler-ubuntu-aniket1            1/1       Running   0          58m
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-54865c6fb9-kg5zt    1/1       Running   0          26m`

When I tried to create kubernetes Dashboard with

`$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml`

and set proxy as

`sh
$ kubectl proxy --address 0.0.0.0 --accept-hosts '.*'
Starting to serve on [::]:8001`

When I hit url `http://<master IP>:8001` in browser, it shows following output

`{
  "paths": [
    "/api",
    "/api/v1",
    "/apis",
    "/apis/",
    "/apis/admissionregistration.k8s.io",
    "/apis/admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io",
    "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/apiregistration.k8s.io",
    "/apis/apiregistration.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/apiregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/apps",
    "/apis/apps/v1",
    "/apis/apps/v1beta1",
    "/apis/apps/v1beta2",
    "/apis/authentication.k8s.io",
    "/apis/authentication.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/authorization.k8s.io",
    "/apis/authorization.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/autoscaling",
    "/apis/autoscaling/v1",
    "/apis/autoscaling/v2beta1",
    "/apis/batch",
    "/apis/batch/v1",
    "/apis/batch/v1beta1",
    "/apis/certificates.k8s.io",
    "/apis/certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/crd.projectcalico.org",
    "/apis/crd.projectcalico.org/v1",
    "/apis/events.k8s.io",
    "/apis/events.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/extensions",
    "/apis/extensions/v1beta1",
    "/apis/networking.k8s.io",
    "/apis/networking.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/policy",
    "/apis/policy/v1beta1",
    "/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io",
    "/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/apis/storage.k8s.io",
    "/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1",
    "/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/healthz",
    "/healthz/autoregister-completion",
    "/healthz/etcd",
    "/healthz/ping",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/apiservice-openapi-controller",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/apiservice-registration-controller",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/apiservice-status-available-controller",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/bootstrap-controller",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/ca-registration",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/generic-apiserver-start-informers",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/kube-apiserver-autoregistration",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/rbac/bootstrap-roles",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-controllers",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-informers",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/start-kube-aggregator-informers",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/start-kube-apiserver-informers",
    "/logs",
    "/metrics",
    "/openapi/v2",
    "/swagger-2.0.0.json",
    "/swagger-2.0.0.pb-v1",
    "/swagger-2.0.0.pb-v1.gz",
    "/swagger.json",
    "/swaggerapi",
    "/version"
  ]
}`

But when I tries to hit `http://<master IP>:8001/ui` I am not able to see Kubernetes dashboard. Instead I see following output

`{
  "paths": [
    "/apis",
    "/apis/",
    "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io",
    "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/healthz",
    "/healthz/etcd",
    "/healthz/ping",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/generic-apiserver-start-informers",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-controllers",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-informers",
    "/metrics",
    "/openapi/v2",
    "/swagger-2.0.0.json",
    "/swagger-2.0.0.pb-v1",
    "/swagger-2.0.0.pb-v1.gz",
    "/swagger.json",
    "/swaggerapi",
    "/version"
  ]
}`

Could you please help me resolving dashboard issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10):

Try go to:

```
http://<master IP>:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
```

As mentioned here: https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard

Comment: Thanks rom. It was working as expected with this URL. I am new at this so was struggling with this dashboard for quite some time. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As mention in [kubernetes/dashboard issue 1803](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/1803):

> changes in kubernetes 1.6 users that want to enable RBACs should configure them first to allow dashboard access to api server.

Make sure you have define a [service account as in here](https://github.com/UNINETT/kubernetes-terraform/blob/master/ansible/roles/cluster_config/templates/dashboard.yaml.j2#L1), to be able to access the dashboard.

See "[**Service Account Permissions**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/#service-account-permissions)":

> Default RBAC policies grant scoped permissions to control-plane components, nodes, and controllers, but **grant no permissions to service accounts outside the “`kube-system`” namespace** (beyond discovery permissions given to all authenticated users).
>
> This allows you to grant particular roles to particular service accounts as needed.
> Fine-grained role bindings provide greater security, but require more effort to administrate.
> Broader grants can give unnecessary (and potentially escalating) API access to service accounts, but are easier to administrate.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue when i was creating my self-hosted kubernetes cluster on aws ec2 machines. I troubleshooted in following way and fixed

```
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa admin@api.example.com (Enter in Master machines from kops installed machine)

$ kubectl proxy --address=0.0.0.0 --port-8001 &

$ ssh -i pemfile username@Ip-address (in machine where you installed kops )

$ cat ~/.kube/config (to get user  name and password )

$ kubectl -n kube-system describe secret admin-user-token-id
```

To get DashBoard

http://MasterIP_address:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/